# Generate rig ruins my animations

Tags: animation, rigging

So I was making my first animations with blender and after I was done I hit generate rig and the rig doesn't have any of the animation data applied to it. The metarig has all of it and if I parent my character to the rig it warps my character in extremely weird ways. Any ideas whats going on??

Comment: If you are working with rigifiy or something like that, you need to know, that metarig is used only for setup, not for animation. I suppose you should remove all transforms from metarig before generation

Comment: I will try this. So then the generated rig is what I use to make the animations? I was using the metarig and moving the joints of the bones and adding keyframes.

Comment: Metarig is not designed for animation, It is used for locating bones and joints in generated rig

Comment: Okay thank you im redoing my metarig then going to try again, this makes sense because the tutorial i was watching somehow had a generated rig without ever showing when he made it. So I assumed he made it after doing the animations not before. Guess I was wrong

Comment: So I tried it again and just like before when I press generate rig the legs turn into spirals. Like as if I was ringing out a cloth thats what my legs are doing. Not at all sure why...

Comment: Remove all weight groups and set armature parent again for generated rig, not for metarig.

Comment: Sadly its the same issue. Its when I try to parent the rig to the character. Parenting a metarig has no issues

Comment: Try clearing all transforms on the metarig. You can either clear all transforms, or if you want to keep your transforms you can apply them.